# На каком основании Дух принимает правки?

Tags: поддержка, дух-сообщества, предлагаемые-правки

Если я не ошибаюсь, для принятия сделанной правки на SO требуется как минимум 2 голоса. Но вот иногда одним из участников, отдающим голос, становится "Дух Сообщества".

Могу предположить, что такая схема включается, когда правка долго ожидает утверждения (т.е. мало активных пользователей) и достаточно хотя бы одного живого голоса для утверждения.

Прав ли я, или тут какой-то иной смысл заложен?

P.S. Кстати, почему-то некоторые правки принимаются [голосами трёх](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/89612), некоторые [двух](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/89611).

Comment: в первом случае скорее всего был выбран вариант: принять и улучшить правку, судя по всему во втором случае - также

Comment: @Grundy в обоих случаях было выбрано `принять и улучшить`. Это видно по ссылкам.

Comment: Тогда в чем заключается вопрос? :-)

Comment: @Grundy в том же, что и изначально. Разве комментарии как-то прояснили ситуацию? :)

Comment: если была нажата кнопка _принять_ нужно набрать сколько-то голосов, вроде от пользователя зависит, если нажата _принять и улучшить_ начальная правка принимается от имени духа и дописывается правка улучшателя

Comment: @Grundy судя по всему, Вы правы.

Comment: @Grundy уже ответил, только потом заметил ваш комментарий.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а разве всегда нужно два положительных голоса? мне кажется попадалось и больше трех на некоторых пользователях. То есть логика определения достаточности голосов для принятия может быть несколько сложнее

Comment: @Grundy если один проголосовал за, а другой против, тогда ждут третьего.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не, мне кажется когда голосуешь за принятие, показывается сообщение, типа для принятия правки нужно еще столько то голосов, и вот там было число не 2 и не 3, а больше

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Для подтверждения правки необходимо два утвердительных голоса от проверяющих. Но есть особый вариант, который вы использовали - "Принять и редактировать".

Когда проверяющий выбирает "Принять и редактировать" правку, то она принимается автоматически, даже если до этого её никто не проверял или предыдущий проверяющий выбрал "Отклонить". Чтобы не нарушать логику сайта, Дух приходит и даёт недостающие голоса в пользу правки.

Если до этого уже был один голос в подтверждение правки, то Дух всё равно приходит. Дух - парень прямолинейный, ему лень разбираться, был там голос или не был. Поэтому получается, что правку подтвердили трое, один из которых - Дух. (Тут самое время удержаться от шуток на религиозные темы)

Предполагается, что даже если правка не очень хороша и до этого один из проверяющих отклонил её, то все недостатки компенсируются последующей правкой опытного проверяющего.

Comment: спасибо, понял)